# Searching a date range using beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, findall

I am trying to download images from website https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/archivepix.html using beautiful soup. This is the specific code:

```
def load():
puts("Loading archive...")
urls = []
data = urllib2.urlopen(ROOT_URL + 'archivepix.html').read()
puts("Opening archive...")
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')
results = soup.find('b').findAll('a')
for result in progress.bar(results):
    urls.append(result['href'])
```

My problem is: every time I run the code ALL pictures download (70,000 plus). How do I use findAll to limit the date range to, for example, 100 or between dates? Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the *limit* argument

`results = ...findAll('a', limit=100)`